# Link or connect facebook comments plugin to comments on fan page wall posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-comments

Facebook comments plugin - as far as I understand, if I have put the facebook comments plugin on a post web page, and the permalink of the post being commented on matches the base URL, then comments are stored via facebook using my post permalink.

Lets say if I post the permalink onto my facebook page wall (which I am the admin of), the open graph tags come into play, all the relavant data is pulled in, fb:admins, fb:app etc.

But is it possible to connect my facebook page (using my facebook page ID) to that permalink - so that comments posted on the page using comment plugin, connect/link with the post comments on my facebook page wall?

Thanks

Comment: i think i've not catched at all what you need, but fb comments are related to the site link passed, so if users comments the same link on the fb page and on your site, you will anyway have all comments on both them sides (related to the link shared):P

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible. We've implemented custom solution using Facebook Application and Facebook Javascript SDK on the website itself. You need to query the comments table of a specific Page post via [FQL](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) using your app access token from your server to retrieve all comments and render them on the page.

Then you need to provide user with several entry points for several states in order to enable posting for them. You need to solve four cases:

1. User doesn't like the page and didn't authorize your app
2. User doesn't like the page and authorized your app
3. User likes the page and didn't authorize your app
4. User likes the page and authorized your app

User needs to like your page and authorize your app with publish_stream permission in order to be able to comment on your page posts via your website. Of course you need to maintain reference between posts on your page and posts on your website.

The website where we did this a few years ago is [BIGGBOSS](http://biggboss.cz/news/2594) click on "Komentáře" and find the same [post on Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/biggbosslabel/posts/471685279546552) with the same comments.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question its not possible to connect the comments from the commentbox, integrated in your non-facebook page (e.g a blog of yours), to the comments which are posted to a post on your fanpage.

The only solution would be to build an custom commentbox with the open-graph and publish the comments to the fanpagepost and additionally extract the comments out of the fanpage to display them on your blog.

But this requires accepting permission dialog before people are able to comment on your blog which would probably decrease the comments made.  You would lose the benefit of the built-in commentbox.